# Matching template string with placeholders in php

Tags: php, regex, string, templates

I have to restrict users to follow already defined set of templates while sending messages. The defined templates can have placeholders as well which the user can replace at runtime.

How can I check, if the message matches already predefined template.

```
// Predefined template
$template = 'Hi {{name}}, Hope you are enjoying our service. See you on {{date}}';
$template = 'Bank will remain closed on {{date}} on account of {{reason}}.';
```

User can write a message like this, which should match the template

```
$message = 'Hi E, Hope you are enjoying our services. See you on 20th Jan';
$template = 'Bank will remain closed on 20th Jan on account of holiday.';
```

This will be an invalid template

```
$message = 'Hi E, Hope we are enjoying your services. See you on 20th Jan';
$template = 'Bank will remain open on 20th Jan on account of holiday.';
```

How can I validate a string with replaced placeholders against the predefined template in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.+?` in place of the `{{wildcard}}`. That will allow for any character until the first occurrence of the next character (and the remaining text). The `.` is any character. The `+` is one or more of the previous character. The `?` tells the `+` to stop at the first occurrence. The `\` are escaping special characters in the string. The leading and trailing `/` are delimiters telling where the regex starts and ends.

PHP Usage:

```
$message[] = 'Hi E, Hope you are enjoying our services. See you on 20th Jan';
$template[] = 'Bank will remain closed on 20th Jan on account of holiday.';
$message[] = 'Hi E, Hope we are enjoying your services. See you on 20th Jan';
$template[] = 'Bank will remain open on 20th Jan on account of holiday.';
$templatem = '/Hi .+?, Hope you are enjoying our services\. See you on .+?/';
$templatet = '/Bank will remain closed on .+? on account of .+?\./';
foreach($message as $key => $mes) {
if(preg_match($templatem, $mes)) {
    echo 'Match' . "\n";
} else {
    echo 'No Match' . "\n";
}
if(preg_match($templatet, $template[$key])) {
    echo 'Match' . "\n";
} else {
    echo 'No Match' . "\n";
}
}
```

Note in your first template you have `service.` but in both examples you have `services.` if you want the `s` to be optional use a `?` after the `s`.

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/501441
Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/cO2oD2/1

Comment: Thanks @chris85 - I could not get `The ? tells the + to stop at the first occurrence.` Also spaces around the placeholder, should not match. like `Hi Ehsan ,` should not match, as it contains space before `,` where as the template has `,` immediately after `placeholder`

Comment: Maybe this would explain that `?` stopping the greediness better, http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#helpful. What should the name placeholder be, just alpha characters? Your dates are going to get difficult going down this path. Maybe for date `\d\d?(?:st|nd|rd|th) [A-Z][a-z]{2}`. Depends on strictness could list all 12 possible months and make the number ranges 1-31 (although feb, april, june, etc would be wrong there, then again feb could be wrong every 4 years..). This answer is a starting point, depends on your strictness.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. This is exactly what I needed.